# How to create answer link for a specific post?

Tags: support, answers, share-this

Sometimes I need to refer an answer to a specific answerer in my post like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431190/understanding-the-effect-of-arguments-on-flatten-method). But I don't know how to make that link. for example the answerer I specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431190/understanding-the-effect-of-arguments-on-flatten-method/21431288#21431288)

I am not understanding what is the number `21431288#21431288`, here - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431190/understanding-the-effect-of-arguments-on-flatten-method/21431288#21431288`. How to get that one ?

I picked this one from user profile. But I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "share" link at the bottom of each answer.

[image: share]

Comment: Ha we made the [same edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24084) at the same time. Shame that you did not like my image. I will leave it [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1kCk1.png) in case you change your mind :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help!!